# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener

Tags: java, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

Don't know how this was working earlier, but I guess I am doing something wrong with my libraries in my web app on tomcat.

It is when I am trying to run a class, from a project deployed on tomcat, I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 18 more
```

Please help.

Comment: Seems multiple jar copies of  java servlet too. one on your application ,and one on tomcat's lib.If so ,  get rid off your applications jar.

Answer (score 0):

**jar** containing `javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener` is missing.so [download this jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxservletjar.htm)
 and then set your **classpath**